# Find final position of object when two forces are applied

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I'm pretty sure this is a stupid question, but I didn't know exactly what to search for to find the answer. Assume that a continuous force (F1) is applied on an object. If a second force (F2), with direction exactly opposite to that of F1 is applied (similar to a jump on a planet). How can I know how far the object will move towards the direction of F2? Also, how much should F2 be for the object to move exactly r meters towards the direction of F2?

This question has a terrible syntax and I'm sorry for that, but I have absolutely no knowledge in physics (I'm barely 13) and I have no idea of exactly what to say or what to search for. Let me use an example:

If a human stands on a planet (earth), a constant force is applied to him (F1, gravity, toward the center of the planet). If he applies a force with a direction opposite to that of the constant force (F2, "upwards" on the planet). How high will the human jump, and how much force (F2) is required for the human to jump r meters high?

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer to your question.

The key concept is $F=ma$. Forces cause accelerations, which are changes in velocity.

If two equal force in opposite directions act on an object, they cancel. That is, two equal and opposite force vectors add up to $0$. The motion is the same as if there were no forces. The acceleration the forces cause is $0$. The change in velocity they cause is $0$.

The object moves at whatever velocity it started with. If that velocity was $0$, the object is stationary. So long as the forces don't change, it never moves.

So long as the forces don't change, if the object had a velocity, it never stops. It never arrives at a final position.

---

You are asking about a somewhat different situation. You have the force of gravity on an object. That force never changes. And then you jump. That is a momentary force. You push yourself upward with your legs until your feet leave the ground. At that point you are not pushing any more.

So that is different from the first situation in two different ways.

- The forces are not equal and opposite.
- The forces change.

When you stand still, your legs push you upward with a force just strong enough to cancel gravity. Likewise if you stand on a skateboard which is traveling at constant velocity.

To jump, you have to push harder than that. During this time, the forces are two vectors in opposite directions, but the upward force is bigger. If you add the vectors, the total force is upward. You accelerate upward and gain an upward velocity. If you know the force and how long you pushed upward, you can figure out the upward velocity from $v = at$.

Once you leave the ground, the only force is gravity. You have an upward velocity and a downward force. You have a downward acceleration, which will decrease your velocity until you stop. It will continue to change your velocity, giving you a downward velocity.

There are more equations that relate distance, velocity, acceleration, and time. Given the velocity with which you leave the ground and the acceleration, you can figure out you high you will go before stopping and falling back down.

Comment: I was asking about the last thing you said. What are those equations? Can I at least know what to search for online?